# Google Analytics: check if ecomerce plugin exists

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the normal Google Analytics (actually, the tag manager, but it doesn't make a difference), on all pages. But sometimes, I want to fire a command for "ecomerce" plugin, only if the plugin has been required. **Is there a way to check if the "ecomerce" plugin exists?**

Note: It isn't that I want the commands to be fired anyway, I really am depending on the lack of the plugin in order not to fire the commands. It is the only way in my project, to prevent the command being called on page refresh.

Comment: It's so nice when you see your post downvoted for no reason provided. Feels like spammers at work!

Comment: I did not downvote, but if you enable e-commerce tracking in GTM then the plugin is loaded, if you don't it isn't.  Since thus you already should know, without further ado, if the plugin is there or not it is hard to understand your use case.

Comment: I don't think you correctly read my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is what you will do. The analytics.js library provides the ga object which you use to send information. Now the only hard part(if you use GTM) is to get the tracker name that you currently use. For a more generic case you might be ok with just

```
var tracker = ga.getAll()[indexOfTheTrackerYouwantToUse]
```

and then you use the method below

```
tracker.plugins_.keys
```

and will output an array with all the plugins on the tracker. Something like

```
["displayfeatures", "ec"]
```

Then you iterate and you find if the plugin you want exists in there.

Comment: I've seen the plugins_ property, but I was hoping for a more official way, those properties are not documented, they can change without warrant.. but this seems as good as it gets.

Comment: Glad i could help